# Why Bitmap DecodeByteArray cannot decode 24-bit (or more) bmp images?

Tags: c#, android, tcp, xamarin.android, bitmap

My project is about an Android (using Xamarin C#) connect to a local server (C++) by TCP, and receive image from this server. I've been trying to use BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray to decode the received byte[] and show it in imageView. But it seems to successfully decode only with the 16 Color (or less) bmp images. If the image is 24-bit or more, the decode return null, or not fully successful decode (some pixels are black). I'm sure that the android received the image data. So I think the problem is in the decode stage. The android C# code is as below:

```
byte[] bmpBuff = new byte[img_size];
// receive image data code //
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bmpBuff, 0, bmpBuff.Length);
```

Can anyone explain me this and help me solve this please? If possible, please tell me how to receive and decode other type of image (JPEG, PNG,...) too. Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: `byte[] bmpBuff = new byte[img_size];` --  This question is tagged as C++, but there is no C++ code in this post.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Does not matter. It is goed to know that the bitmap is produced by C++. Storing a bitmap as bytes can differ.

Comment: Then maybe the test code should first be written in C++ to verify the C++ sender is working correctly?

Comment: In general BitmapFactory can only decode array types which it can encode itself. Did you investigate?

Comment: `If possible, please tell me how to receive and decode other type of image (JPEG, PNG,...) ` Well that is much easier as then you can use BitmapFactory.decodeBytes().

Comment: Thank you very much. But my question is why it can decode 16-bit image but not 24-bit? I don't understand

Comment: I tried to explain that in a comment. Repeat: `In general BitmapFactory can only decode array types which it can encode itself. Did you investigate?`

Comment: Sure. I'll do that. Btw, I cannot find BitmapFactory.decodeBytes(). Do you mean decodeFile() ?

Comment: You confused me with your post/code. BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray can only be used for quote: `byte: byte array of compressed image data`. Hence for .jpg or .png. Offering bitmap bytes will not work then. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)

Answer (score 0):

If you received a bitmap then use code like

```
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer();
```

Test with

```
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer();
```